# Use of a cubemap as environment map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, world

in both Cycles and EEVEE, I can easily set an environment map using the nodes (Environment map node -> World) and use an equirectangular image as source. Equirectangular images are not very good at the poles, since they show a high distortion over there, why there is no way to use directly a cube map as environment map?
As far as I understand, an environment map in Blender is:
- the backdrop
- what it is used for illumination
- what it is used for reflections
- what it is used for shadows

Is it correct? Since AFAIK cubemaps are supported natevely from OpenGL, why aren't they directly usable in Blender? Of course I can put a large emitting cube in my scene, but I would do the same with an equirectangular image mapped on a large sphere, so why equirectangular are supported by using nodes and for cubemaps I have to build the cube myself?

Or am I missing something?